# Tocando musica mp3 em Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

tudo bem?
bem eu venho aqui pedir uma solução referente a tocar musica mp3 em Python.
Eu importei a biblioteca do Pygame e utilizei o módulo mixer para tocar musicas em python:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('brain_damage.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=0.0)
pygame.event.wait()
```

Após eu escrever esse script e rodar o meu programa, ele dá uma saída de erro, dizendo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/gabriel/Documentos/GitHub/Projetos Pessoais/olamundo.py/_exercicios/teste.py", line 3, in <module>

pygame.mixer.music.load('music/brain_damage.mp3')
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'music/brain_damage.mp3'
```

[image: Esse é o arquivo Python que fica dando erro]

Para efeito de comparação, eu criei um outro arquivo Python e utilizei o mesmo código da imagem acima, e para a minha surpresa, o mixer conseguiu rodar o meu arquivo mp3. Vocês sabem o por quê procede?
[image: Segundo print com o programa rodando]

Comment: você verificou se a musica está na mesma pasta que o código?

Comment: sim, ela está na mesma pasta do código

Comment: o arquivo mp3 não está na pasta "music", nesta pasta estão apenas alguns arquivos.wav. A musica que eu quero tocar no meu programa está na pasta chamada "_exercicios" junto com o código

Comment: Que SO é esse que você tá usando?

Answer (score 1):

Caso o mp3 esteja na mesma pasta do script:

```
from pygame import mixer 

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('brain_damage.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Caso a pasta do mp3 esteja no mesmo nível do script você adiciona um `.`:

```
from pygame import mixer 

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('./teste/brain_damage.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Caso a pasta esteja um nível acima do script você adiciona dois `.`

```
from pygame import mixer 

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('../teste/brain_damage.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Você pode colocar o caminho completo no load, exemplo: `F:/stackoverflow/teste/brain_damage.mp3`

O caminho `teste` é fictício, você deve verificar o caminho para o arquivo em questão.

Comment: Opa vlw ai glr, eu consegui arrumar esse bug. Era realmente o nível da pasta!

Comment: como eu coloquei as musicas em uma pasta separada, eu inseri o ".." dois ponto, e meus scripts funcionaram. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Gabriel, boa tarde! Por nada! Que bom que resolveu o problema! Abraços!

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir a outra resposta, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 